# how to configure security for admins and user separately spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to secure demo application with jwt token based authentication. My usecase is I have two type of users one is teacher which is admin and other is student which is normal user.

I want to configure a security for teacher and student separately. I have different sources for user authentication — one for teachers and one for normal users. If have configured two webseconfigadapters.

In StudentWebConfigAdapter

```
      config() {       
        http.antMatcher("/student/getmarks/{id}")
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
   }
    @Bean("studentAuth")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
```

In TeacherWebConfigAdapter

```
   config() {       
    http.antMatcher("/student/**","/teacher/**")
       .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
   }
    @Bean("teacherAuth")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
```

How do I configure seperate authentication manager for both. I tried by creating separate bean with different names. it is giving error authentication manager should be only one.

`Expecting to only find a single bean for type interface org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager, but found [studentAuth, teacherAuth]`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its help for you..

```
 set your group for page in secconfig:
 .antMatchers("/page").hasAnyAuthority("USER,ADMIN").anyRequest()
  and than you can work with groups in thymeleaf:
 <div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ADMIN')"></div>
```

or in controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/index"}, method =RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model, Principal principal) {
    Collection<?> auth = 
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();

    if(auth.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN")) 
    {
        return "pages/indexForUser";
    }
    else if(auth.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER")))
    {
        return "pages/indexForTeacher";
    }
    //ROLE_ANONYMOUS
}
```